# Find the 2017 smallest positive integer that gains an extra digit when doubled.

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I know the first term is 5
It's continues till 9
And then there's a break in the series and then resumes at 50 and till 90.
But can I get a more formal way?

Comment: So, $5-9$ work, then $50-99$, then $500-999$...do you see a pattern?

Comment: Yeah I know of this method....Wanted a better approach...Well if this is the on!Y one then ok.well thank u

Answer (score 1):

How many numbers with exactly $n$ digits that satisfy the property are there?

$$(10^n-1)-(10^n/2-1)=10^n/2$$

How many numbers with at most $n$ digits that satisfy the property are there?

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{10^n}2=\frac{10^{n+1}-10}{18}=\frac59\cdot \underbrace{99\ldots9}_{n\text{ nines}}=\underbrace{55\ldots5}_{n\text{ fives}}$$

Since $f(3)=555$ and $f(4)=5555$, the last of those $2017$ numbers has four digits, so it is
$$4999+2017-555=6461$$

Comment: Ummm....I did not understand that last step

Comment: Please tell me!

Comment: The $556$th number is $5000=4999+556-555$. The $557$th number is $5001=4999+557-555$, etc.

Comment: How can u tell that the 556th no. Is the given expression...ik it's a dumb question but please tell

Comment: And how did u get that first expression?Guess or theorem?

Comment: Follow it through for three digits.  The lowest three digit number that carries is $500$, the last is $999$.  Those are the two terms on the left.  That accounts for $999-500+1=500$ numbers.